# MySQL (MyISAM) - update field to greatest of two fields from different tables

Tags: mysql, multi-table

I have two tables, `t1` and `t2` with two columns each - `id_user` and `age`.
How do I update `t1.age` to the greatest of `t1.age` and `t2.age` for matching ID's and leave `t1.age` unchanged if there is no matching ID in `t2`.

Before update:

```
t1  
+-------+---+   
|id_user|age|  
+-------+---+   
|      1|  5|  
+-------+---+   
|      2| 10|  
+-------+---+   
|      3| 10|  
+-------+---+   

t2
+-------+---+   
|id_user|age|  
+-------+---+   
|      2| 12|  
+-------+---+   
|      3|  8|  
+-------+---+   
|      4| 20|  
+-------+---+
```

After update:

```
t1  
+-------+---+   
|id_user|age|  
+-------+---+   
|      1|  5|  
+-------+---+   
|      2| 12|  
+-------+---+   
|      3| 10|  
+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
UPDATE  t1
JOIN    t2 ON (t2.id_user = t1.id_user)
SET     t1.age = t2.age
WHERE   t2.age > t1.age;
```

Test Case:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id_user int, age int);
CREATE TABLE t2 (id_user int, age int);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 10);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3, 10);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2, 12);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (4, 20);
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
+---------+------+
| id_user | age  |
+---------+------+
|       1 |    5 |
|       2 |   12 |
|       3 |   10 |
+---------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET age = T2.age
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t2.id_user = t1.id_user
WHERE t2.age > t1.age
```

Comment: I don't think you *don't* need a `FROM` in there :)

Comment: Really?  I come from a SQL Server background where such niceness is required - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: MySQL won't appreciate :) ... BTW: I had a typo in the above comment. I obviously intended "I *don't* think you need a `FROM`..."

Comment: :) - the MySQL syntax does look pretty clean for this, I'll bear it in mind for the future.  I got what you meant, sir - I didn't think I didn't need a FROM.  ;)